# How to make a draggable image in div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move a image in a div like a facebook cover page, but it is not moving smoothly with image tag . when I put this image in a div like a background image it is working 
my js code is ..

```
var draggable = function(element) {
    element.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (e.target != element)
            return;
        var offsetX = e.pageX - element.offsetLeft;
        var offsetY = e.pageY - element.offsetTop;
        function move(e) {
            var ele = document.getElementById('ele');
            var width = 400-ele.clientWidth;
            var height = 400-ele.clientHeight;
            element.style.left = (e.pageX - offsetX) + 'px';
            element.style.top = (e.pageY - offsetY) + 'px';
        }
        function stop(e) {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', move);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', stop);
        }
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', move);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', stop);
    });
}

function init() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('ele');
    draggable(ele);
}
```

and my html code which is not working is..

```
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="testdiv" style="position:relative;left:100px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #ccc;width:400px;height:400px">
        <img src="Desert.jpg" id="ele" style="position:absolute;"></img>
    </div>
</body>
```

and this code is working..

```
<body onload="init();">
    <div id="testdiv" style="position:relative;left:100px;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #ccc;width:400px;height:400px">
        <div id="ele" style="width:100%; height:100%; background-color: gray; position:absolute; background-image:url( 'Desert.jpg' );"></div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you finding a solution to aligning image inside a div? Could you please provide a JSFiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sD92R/

Comment: If you remove the `init();` function in your code and on `<body>` it's working. http://jsfiddle.net/sD92R/4/ - but I guess that is not what you want?

Comment: ya it is working but when I did mouseup , it is still moving image

Comment: i want to move a image onmouse down and stop on mouseup..

Comment: I think you should check the coordinate to do that

Comment: how coordinate effect in this metter

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to this question, which handles the same idea of dragging images, althought the question is slightly different. Check out his/her JSFiddle from question.

[Check it out here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951328/css-z-index-doesnt-work-prperly-when-i-append-the-new-div-element)

Comment: i am getting this problem with image tag.

Answer (score -1):

`<img>` is a self-closing tag. You don't need the `</img>` as it's not valid. Remove that and it should work fine. Depending on your `doctype` you should use:

**HTML5**

```
<img src="Desert.jpg" id="ele" style="position:absolute;">
```

**XHTML** *(note the `/` at the end of the tag)*

```
<img src="Desert.jpg" id="ele" style="position:absolute;" />
```

Comment: This isn't an  answer... Any recommendations or advice should be posted in the comments