# CSS: z-index doesn't work prperly when i append the new div element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I want to implement the website about draw some rectangles and stickers configured by div element.

To add sticker or rectangle, User click the button.

I want to arrange div element in the order of below

(upper) sticker > rack > rectangle > canvas (lower)

So I used z-index in style sheet.

```
#canvas {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    ...
}

.rectangle {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 2 !important;
    ...
}

.rack {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 3 !important;
    ...
}

.sticker { 
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 4 !important;
    ...
}
```

It works well, when elements are allocated by html code.

```
<div id="canvas">
    <div class="rectangle draggable resizable"
        style="left:0px; top:0px; width:200px; height:300px;"
        type="rectangle" id="rectangle_org">

        <div class="rack draggable resizable"
            style ="left: 0; top:40px; width: 50px; height: 100px;"></div>

        <div class="sticker sticker_green draggable"
            type="sticker" id="green"
            style="left:0px; top:0px;">
        </div>

        <div class="sticker sticker_yellow draggable"
            type="sticker" id="yellow"
            style="left:30px; top:0px;"></div>

        <div class="sticker sticker_red draggable"
            type="sticker" id="red"
            style="left:60px; top:0px;">
        </div>

        <div class="sticker sticker_gray draggable"
            type="sticker" id="gray"
            style="left:90px; top:0px;">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

When I clicked the button to append element to canvas, it doen't work properly.

the new rectangle cover the stickers, even though the z-index of the rectangle is lower than sticker's.

I think the z-index of these are like below

(upper) new sticker > new rack > new rectangle > old sticker > old rack > old rectangle (lower)

How can i fix this error.

Please refer this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/crisply/bD35Z/9/)

Comment: Works OK in Chrome/Windows, Firefox/Windows - rectanlge always under sticker. Please specify your own browser and chek in others.

Comment: the problem is occurred, when i append the new element...

Comment: To be clear, I tried with element spawner buttons, different order, dragging them etc etc, and it still worked. So it may be either problem with your browser or I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: do you mean, when you append the rectangle, the stickers that appended already are over the new rectangle?

Comment: Yes, both in Chrome and FF. I could not make any (old/new) sticker to appear under any (old/new) rectangle.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I think i need to test another computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you append a new element to the DOM the `z-index` goes back to `0`. I haven't tested this on other browsers, but it happens in Chrome.

You have to either set `z-index` manually on the appended element, or code some logic to automatically assign `z-index` values to your elements.

Answer (score 2):

in order to use the z-index proprety **you have to** define the **position** of the div in **css** to either : **absolute,relative or fixed**

Comment: Yes i defined the position. but it doen't work.. please refer my fiddld on the question.

Comment: Yes but i want to retain this order "sticker>rack>rectangle>canvas"

Answer (score 0):

What @Pier mentioned seems to be right. Adding

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the block you already created in JS seems to work and stickers no longer are covered by it. But if you want to create more than 1 block, then this trick stops working (because accordingly to the answer above- z-index in the whole website goes back to 0 or sth like that)